# Degree Of array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

we have given array like a=[1,2,3,4,1,2,1,1,1,2,2] 
so we have find duplicate element from the array and separate the array like [1,1,1,1,1] and [2,2,2,2] and print only largest length of array so here largest length is 5 which is [1,1,1,1,1].Here i try to use itertools but not work out.

Input is a=[1,2,3,1,1,1,1,2,2,2]

o/p should be 5.

```html
import itertools

my_list = [1,2,2,2,1,1,2,2,2,3,4]





num1=[]

for a, b in itertools.combinations(my_list,2):
    if a == b:
        num1.append(b)

print(num1)
max_ele=max(num1)
print(max_ele)
print(num1.count(max_ele))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter

N = [1,2,2,2,1,1,2,2,2,3,4]
C = Counter(N)

count = max(C.values())
print(count)
```

Comment: you right but how can i print list like [2,2,2,2,2,2] and [1,1,1].

Comment: @Nishit `print([ [k,]*v for k,v in C.items()])` will probably dowhat you want